# Large files upload using multipartfile cause long interval before tomcat response

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, upload

I'm using CommonsMultipartResolver in spring to handle file uploading. The configuration is like

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

The Controller is like

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadImageData")
public ModelAndView uploadImageData(@RequestParam(value = "imageDataFile", required = false) MultipartFile[] multipartFiles) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
```

//
}

Here comes the problem. When the files chosen were very large like about 100M, limited by the bandwidth, there will be 10-20min before the controller get the request. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Add this snippet of code in your Dispatcher-Servlet.xml, `<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />`. This will allow to upload file with in this range.

Comment: you can give async task in background for uploading.